# Rails is hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started up my rails server and when I accessed the route i got an odd error.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-09-20 12:05:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-20 12:05:55] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-09-20 12:05:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=27864 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-20 12:06:00 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
```

This is all that happens. When i change paths in the client address bar, nothing changes.

I have not changed anything. I even rolled back to a previous version thinking I was missing something.

I have also uninstalled and re installed my version of ruby (currently 2.2.2p95)

I have reinstalled all gems.

not sure if its a ruby issue, but I don't know where to go next.

UPDATE::
Basically its taking 4 minutes per request

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-20 12:26:50 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 231026ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-20 12:30:41 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (44.4ms)
  Rendered nav/_fixed_top.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered nav/_main_nav.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_msg.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 497ms (Views: 489.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

Comment: try to remove all the code in index method and thn try again with empty view file.

Comment: and disable all before and after actions

Comment: BTW what gems do you use?

Comment: Where is error? Log file looks good

Comment: so this is my environment..  I have tried other rails apps and have gotten the same behavior. 

there is no error throwing. It just hangs at the `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load`

Comment: @R.J.Robinson check your database configuration. This is database problem.

Comment: Thanks. So i have tried it with both a mySQL rails app, a Postgresql rails app, and a SQLite3 Rails app. I let it run for 10 minutes, and it finally loaded...

Comment: But each request takes between 4 - 6 minutes to load?

Comment: Here is the trace for the hang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into the dependencies. It seems as if the Ruby Dependency API was having issues, causing me the hang time.

It has since been resolved.

Comment: Please provide a real solution, many people still experience this and looking for a fix